# цикл for (задача,полуелка)

Tags: javascript

```
*
**
***
****

//нужно вот такая полуелка

//у меня пока вот так

for(t=1; t<=4;t++){
    for(n=1;n<=1;n++){
        document.write("*")
    }
    document.write("<br>")
}

//нужно код исключительно из for
```

```js
    for(t=1; t<=4;t++){
        for(n=1;n<=1;n++){
            document.write("*")
        }
        document.write("<br>")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
for (t = 1; t <= 4; t++) {
  for (n = 1; n <= t; n++) {
    document.write("*")
  }
  document.write("<br>")
}
```

---

```js
let str = "";
for (let t = 0; t < 4; t++) 
  document.write((str = str + "*") + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 4):

- Первый цикл отвечает за длинну ёлки (кол-во звёзд по вертикали).
- Второй цикл отвечает для ширину ёлки (кол-во звёзд в ряду).

Т.к. нам надо чтобы кол-во здвёзд с каждым рядом увеличивалось, то указываем сколько раз должен повторится цикл со счетчиком `j` с помощью такого условия `j <= i`.

```js
const width = 4;

for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    document.write("*");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну или так в функциональном стиле.

Заменяем циклы for на метод [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach(t => {
          Array(t).fill(1).forEach(_=> document.write("*")); 
          document.write("<br>");
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с использованием одного цикла

```
let width = 4,
    symbol = '*';

for (let i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
    document.write( symbol.repeat(i) );
    document.write( '<br>' );
}
```